# Saving data to child in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a small application where users can upvote or downvote players based on their recent performance in various sports.

When the upvote button is currently clicked, the UID of the voter (logged in via Google) is supposed to get pushed into the database of the corresponding player who was voted on. Like this:

[image]

However, instead, it's currently doing this: 
[image]

Here is the code which is doing the Firebase work. I believe it is one of these lines that I have wrong.

> this.database.child(playerId).transaction

or

> ref = firebase.database().ref('players/voters');

The code:

```
this.database = firebase.database().ref().child('players');

upvotePlayer(playerId) {
this.state.user ?
  this.database.child(playerId).transaction(function (player) {
    if (player) {
      console.log("UID: " + uid)
      var ref = firebase.database().ref('players/voters');
      ref.child(uid).set(1);
    }
    return player;
  })
  :
  console.log("Must be logged in to vote.")

  }
```

Comment: okay the playerid is the uid or the pushid?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. playerId is the unique ID given to the push for each athlete in firebase -L3vkv.. etc., in the image example. The UID of the logged in voter is just uid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're storing the votes in this path `players/voters` while it should be in this path `players/$playerId/voters`

checkout this

```
this.database = firebase.database().ref().child('players');

upvotePlayer(playerId) {
    this.state.user ?
        this.database.child(playerId).transaction(function (player) {
            if (player) {
                console.log("UID: " + uid)
                var ref = firebase.database().ref('players/' + playerId + '/voters');
                ref.child(uid).set(1);
            }
            return player;
        })
        :
        console.log("Must be logged in to vote.")
}
```

---

[`transaction`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) method have `transactionUpdate` function as argument which should return the new value and you didn't return any , also I think better solution is not use transaction

### Edit : solution without transaction

```
upvotePlayer(playerId) 
{
    if(this.state.user)
    {
        let ref = firebase.database().ref('players/' + playerId + '/voters');
        ref.child(uid).set(1);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Must be logged in to vote.")
    }
}
```

Comment: 'voters' successfully shows briefly where it should, but turns red and disappears in Firebase, as are the other solutions. Any ideas why?

Comment: that because you use transaction , if I was in your situation I will not use transaction , checkout the edit

Comment: Thank you — I wasn't fully aware of the nature of the transaction function. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of this:

```
 var ref = firebase.database().ref('players/voters');
```

it is adding the `voters` under the `players` node and not under the `push id` node.

So you have to retrieve the pushid from the database and then do this:

```
  var ref=firebase.database().ref().child('players').child(playerId).child('voters');
```

so the voters will become one of the `pushid` child.

**For Future Viewers:**

It is better to use transactions since:

> Using a transaction prevents upvote counts from being incorrect if multiple users upvote the same post at the same time or the client had stale data

Comment: That seems to be about right. The problem is, when I click upvote and look at the firebase database, it shows voters appear, but turns red and disappears. The data isn't staying for some reason

Comment: are you adding this `ref.child(uid).set(1);`? Is any other data appearing after it shows red?

Comment: Yes, thats with that line added in. Without that line, nothing ever appears in the db. No other data appears, just the voters.

Comment: yes you have to write that line. try this `ref.child(uid).update(1);` instead of this `ref.child(uid).set(1);`  @idlehand

Comment: Error: Reference.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace. — > 137 |         ref.child(uid).update(1);

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are pushing the value to payers node with player id. you have push the data to child node of players id `voters`. Try this code:-

```
this.database = firebase.database().ref().child('players');

upvotePlayer(playerId) {
this.state.user ?
  this.database.child(playerId).transaction(function (player) {
    if (player) {
      console.log("UID: " + uid)
      player.ref.child(voters).push(uid);
    }
    return player;
  })
  console.log("Must be logged in to vote.")

  }
```

Problem is your are actually taking the reference of `players` node and creating new node at same level of playerid named `voters`. Below line just create a new node `voters` at same level to `playerid`.

```
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('players/voters');
  ref.child(uid).set(1);
```

as you can see there is no node named `voters` in `players` root node. But you are setting the value so it is been created with new data using `set()` function